# [MAUI]When placing templatedView inside the listView's ItemTemplate is not working properly

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, maui, collectionview

When placing the TemplatedView in the ListView's ItemTemplate, the items are not visible on the view, although the selection is occurring even when the items are not loaded onto the view.

I attempted the same with a CollectionView and encountered same results.
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcPof.png)
Code snippet

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding BookInfo}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <TemplatedView>
                        <TemplatedView.ControlTemplate>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid Padding="10">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.4*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.6*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding BookName}"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       TextColor="Teal"
                                       FontSize="21" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                       Text="{Binding BookDescription}"
                                       TextColor="Teal"
                                       FontSize="15" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </TemplatedView.ControlTemplate>
                    </TemplatedView>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: what purpose does using `TemplatedView` serve?  Why not place the `Grid` directly inside the `ViewCell`?

Comment: I want use my own control template with content presenter

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to use `ContentPresenter` and when I see your current code I think this is what you are after.

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="BookTemplate">
        <Grid Padding="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.4*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.6*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Book">
            <ViewCell>
                <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource BookTemplate}">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="9"
                                Text="{Binding BookName}"
                                TextColor="Teal" />
                        <Label
                                FontSize="9"
                                Text="{Binding BookDescription}"
                                TextColor="Teal" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentView>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```